# Sending Skinny / sccp message to iKettle using TCP in command line / unix

Tags: tcp, wifi, iot

I'm trying to access my "smart kettle",
first I entered it's own, unencrypted Wi-Fi and typed nmap 192.168.1.1, these ports are open:

23/tcp   open  telnet
80/tcp   open  http
2000/tcp open  cisco-sccp

accessing port 23 with telnet was easy,
now I'm searching for a tool to send hex messages to port 2000 to turn on/ shut down the device.

Is there a tool to send skinny protocol messages?
And if not, how could I communicate with port 2000 over the command line?

Thanks in advance!